# AWS Lambda invocation takes a lot of time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge

My team has a strange problem with our Lambda invocations, which seem to behave strangely from time to time. We are well aware of the cold start time and we addressed that with warmup Lambdas, but this is really strange.

Below I attached an image of the timeframe of a Lamba function invocation.

I takes 5-6 seconds for coldstart to happen, then the function runs for 700ms (billed period) and it again takes 5-6 second for response to happen. This happens a few time per hour, but it influences our apps badly becouse the app's rendering is impacted.

Anybody have a clue what is going on here?

[image]

Comment: How often are you running your warmup lambda to keep this specific lambda warm? If you aren't keeping it warm often enough then this could cause cold starts to still happen.

Comment: Every 5 mins. Cold start is taking only 1/3 of the time here. We don't have a clue what the other 2/3rds are?

Comment: Is this Lambda VPC attached? Do you have provisioned concurrency set up?

Comment: Yes it is VPC attached. Can you give me more info about provisioned concurrency, please?

Comment: @Leon https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html

Comment: There seems to be a much deeper issue. No luck on the AWS forum also... https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?start=0&threadID=226136&tstart=0